# What is a Team Guide?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

My group is trying out the new Stack Overflow for Teams, and I see that I can make users a "Team Guide". What does this do, and what is a Team Guide?

Answer (score 12):

If you click the <kbd>**Invite Team Guides**</kbd> button, you'll see a modal with the following statement:

> Your Team Guides will create starter questions and answers, and help your team become self-sustaining over time.

[image: Team Guides Modal]

Another way of saying it: Team Guides are champions for your Team. They encourage others to get involved, they ask and answer questions, they upvote, comment, identify others who could answer questions, and so on. They help Team owners create a successful Team.

Comment: Do they have any special features or premissions from beeing a "team leader"?